# The present simple and present perfect ( can you help me distinguish and give me examples. Thanks

Tags: grammar

What are the differences between "it is deleted", "it has been deleted", "it was deleted"?

Comment: Hello english learner, and welcome to ELL! Please edit your question to tell us what you already understand about those tenses so people answering don't waste time saying things you already know. A complete answer to your question now would be too long for this site. Please also include the context you're trying to use or understand the language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Participles are tricky. The difference between present perfect and simple past is tricky. Perfect-passive participles are used to form perfect tenses and passive modes.

Participles are inflected forms of a root verb. They can be used as part of a phrasal verb, or as an adjective, or (in the case of present participles) as a noun.

The three cases you ask about all effectively mean the same thing, but they have slightly different flavors.

I think the best way to interpret

> It is deleted

is to interpret “deleted” here as an adjective. Currently, it, whatever it is, is absent, not present, gone. It says nothing about when this happened. The tense is the present tense and refers to the instant of speaking.

The other two are different. Here the participles are acting as part of a verb and indicate when it was deleted. The “was deleted” simply says that the deletion occurred in the past. The “has been deleted” indicates that deletion occurred in the past, but also indicates that deletion occurred relatively recently or that the deletion is currently relevant (it has not been restored).

The past tense is the normal way to speak about a past, completed event.

The present perfect is used to emphasize completion in the past, to indicate completion in the recent past, or to indicate completion that is currently relevant.